# Should I use a JavaScript validator?

Tags: javascript, validation

I've tested my JavaScript in several browsers and it all works fine. However when I run it through [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/), there are a few (minor) errors it picks up.

If the code works, is it important to fix these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the code works, then they probably aren't errors. JSLint is a Lint, not a validator and a very large part of what it does is enforce Douglas Crockford's ideas about best practices.

That said, they are mostly pretty good best practices, and following them is usually a good idea.

Comment: +1. I disagree with Crockford on quite a few things but his ideas are generally sound.

Comment: Yup. And having a well thought out reason for such a disagreement is an excellent reason for ignoring a warning from JSLint. If, OTOH, someone doesn't know why they want to ignore a warning, it is better to follow the advice until you can get more information and form either agreement or disagreement.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say yes.  If JSLint is telling you something is wrong, best to act on it.

Personally, knowing there were errors would nag me.  I wouldn't be deterred by the fact that the code "works".  I couldn't be certain that these "minor" errors - your judgment - would not cause a problem in the future.